# i am trying to crop image in php file by sending a reader.readAsDataURL(blob) input

Tags: javascript, php, image

i am trying to crop image in PHP file by sending a blob from JavaScript. 
,imagecopyresampled function needs image as second parameter, i am not able to create image in php file. Input is received in this form (data:image/jpeg;base64,/........).
Can anybody help me out please. 
here is my php file code:

```
<?php 

$img_name = $_POST['name'];
$data = base64_decode($img_name);
$crop_start_x = $_POST['crop_start_x'];
$crop_start_y = $_POST['crop_start_y'];
$crop_width = $_POST['crop_width'];
$crop_height = $_POST['crop_height'];

$dst_x = 0;
$dst_y = 0;
$src_x = $crop_start_x;
$src_y = $crop_start_y;
$dst_w = $crop_width;
$dst_h = $crop_height;
$src_w = $src_x + $dst_w;
$src_h = $src_y + $dst_h;

$dst_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_w, $dst_h);
$src_image = imagecreatefromstring('$data');

imagecopyresampled($dst_image, $src_image, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_w, $dst_h, $src_w, $src_h);

?>
```

Comment: You are literally trying to convert the string `'$data'` to an image. You need `imagecreatefromstring($data)`.

Comment: it returns that data is not in a recognized format

Answer (score 0):

As was illustrated in comments, the call to [imagecreatefromstring()](http://php.net/imagecreatefromstring) contains a string literal `$data`. In order to use the value contained in `$data`. either use double-quotes (i.e. depnding on [variable parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)):

```
$src_image = imagecreatefromstring("$data");
```

Or no quotes at all:

```
$src_image = imagecreatefromstring($data);
```

See a demonstration in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/j5vm-kbd0).